# Is it possible to have a non mathematical explanation of the dependence of Pair Production cross section with energy?

Tags: photoelectric-effect, pair-production

Cross section of pair production with interaction of photon increases with energy. But why does that happen? I want a non mathematical answer on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A photon, no matter how much energy it has, will not turn into a pair of particles because of conservation of momentum  and energy. The photon does not have a center of mass because it has no rest frame . Any pair of particle-antiparticle will have a rest frame, so there is a [reductio ad absurdium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum).

In order for a pair to appear there must exist a  target nucleus which will interact with the gamma and together with the pair obey energy and momentum conservation, the nucleus taking up momentum and energy.

[So any cross section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Cross_section) will depend on the nucleus, i.e. the target, that the gamma hits. There are tables on this, depending on the nucleus.

This is a simple Feynman diagram that also shows pictorially  what is necessary to get a cross section to first order:

[image: pairprod]

> Feynman Diagram of electron-positron pair production. One can calculate multiple diagrams to get the cross section

Thus the cross section will depend on the field of the particular nucleus. [For example this plot](https://www.physi.uni-heidelberg.de/Publications/Maria_Heinz_Bachelor_thesis.pdf) (fig 2.2) has the cross sections calculated for pair production in carbon, for the specific needs of an experiment:

[image: gammacross]

The cross section rises with energy because  the higher the energy of the gamma, the more it  penetrates the nucleus, where the electric fields are stronger,(1/r^2). Higher frequencies probe smaller distances, and the probability of interacting with the electric field larger. There is a saturation when the gamma energy is high enough, it will  scatter with the quarks which exist in the nuclei, and [create jets.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(particle_physics)) The specific pair production crossection reaches a plateau.  Also as the energy rises, more pair production channels will open .

This is about non mathematical as I can get.